# How does this code works and what is the ouput.. This looks simple

Tags: java, output, logic

When I execute below code, it gives me 13 as answer. I don't understand how that works?

```
package Assignment_One;

class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int this_number = 3;
        int that_number;

        while(this_number<10) {
            that_number=this_number;
            this_number = that_number+this_number/2;
        }
        System.out.println("Answer is:"   + this_number);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to tag the language it is in first. Then you can take a debugger, run the code line by line looking at the variable values and determine how it works.

Answer (score 1):

this_number goes through the following changes:

-> 3 
-> 3 + [int(3/2) = 1] = 4  
-> 4 + [int(4/2) = 2] = 6 
-> 6 + [int(6/2) = 3] = 9 
-> 9 + [int(9/2) = 4] = 13

After this, the condition under the while loop is violated, so it breaks out of loop.

Could you be more specific which part didn't you understand? Do you have problem with loops or the following line:

`this_number = that_number+this_number/2;`

Comment: Yes @umakant . miss understood this statement - this_number = that_number+this_number/2;..... i wasn't following basic arithmetic rules 3 + [int(3/2) = 1] = 4 ....... Thanks